# Jersey Marshalling Member List Issue

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I'm using Java Jersey 1.x to marshall an object that has several members, one of which is a list. All member variables are getting marshalled properly and returned with the correct return type. However, it doesn't include the `objectList` in the return data.

Example:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ClassWithList {
    private String front;
    private int total;
    private ArrayList<AnotherPOJOObject> objectList;
...
getters/setters
```

Getter:

```
public List<AnotherPOJOObject> getObjectList() {
    return objectList;
}
```

I debugged it and checked that objectList is indeed populated with data. 
 `AnotherPOJOObject` is also annotated as an `XmlRootElement`

Comment: Do you have a public getter/seter for objectList?

Comment: @Oleksi: Yes, I've updated my question to include it.

Comment: Do you have an `@XmlElement` annotation on your `getObjectList()` method?

Comment: @user463324: Why would that be necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion to basiljames, I was able to get closer to the answer. The real issue was that the List of `AnotherPOJOOject` wasn't so plain after all. Each object had an untyped `Map` of it's own, and that threw the Marshaller into a fit, because, it always wants to know the type of an object.

I guess the takeaway from this answer to make sure that every collection you return has a well defined type!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html . It details how JAXB will attempt to serialize POJOs. In particular note that it defaults to public members only - which means that "Every public getter/setter pair and every public field will be automatically bound to XML, unless annotated by XmlTransient". In this case I'm guessing that you don't have a public setter field for objectList so JAXB won't serialize it. To get the list to serialize you could:

- Add a public setter method for objectList
- Declare objectList as public (probably not a good idea)
- Add an `@XmlElement` annotation to the getter to explicitly tell JAXB to marshal the list to XML.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue and solved after some trial and error.

Try giving the annotation `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "orders")` to `getObjectList()` and also make the type to `private List<AnotherPOJOObject> objectList;`